# How do I add all features of a Geometric Network to the the dataframe with one parameter in a custom tool that uses python?

Tags: arcpy, geometric-network

I want to add all the Feature Classes of a Geometric Network to my data frame with python.  I want the user to be able to select the dataset of their choosing in a tool, so it would use one parameter.  I want to then use the added Feature Classes to the data frame to run the rest of the script, which I am pretty sure I can figure out once I get the layers in the map.  Does anyone have any ideas? Sorry, this is probably a rudimentary question, but I am new to python.

Comment: That's a lot of "I want", what have you done so far? You neither state what version of ArcGIS you are using, license level, is it a python script tool or a python AddIn you are trying to create and show no code that you have developed or the format your data is stored in. So _I want_ you to update your question to help us help you!